# how to sort a map by its key's under score occurrences

Tags: java, algorithm

i have a map having

```
map.put("100_101","lll")
map.put("100_102","lll")
map.put("100_101_103","lll")
map.put("100_101_104","lll")
map.put("100","lll")
```

expected result is order by map key number of underscore occurrences.

```
map.put("100","lll")
map.put("100_101","lll")
map.put("100_102","lll")
map.put("100_101_103","lll")
map.put("100_101_104","lll")
```

Comment: Which `Map` are you talking about? You can't generally "sort a map", as they have no order. Also it sounds like you shouldn't be using a `String` as the key at all.

Comment: where you are using this. can you past the example here.

Comment: And what's the question? Do you expect us to write your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SortedMap & TreeMap

your Code Should be like that:

```
 SortedMap<String, String>   map = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
   if(o1.length()==o2.length()&&o1.contains("_")&&o1.contains("_"))
  {
       String temp1,temp2;
   temp1=o1.substring(o1.lastIndexOf("_"));
    temp2=o2.substring(o2.lastIndexOf("_"));
    return temp1.compareTo(temp2);
   }
   else  if(o1.length()>o2.length())
  {

    return 1;
   }
   else  if(o1.length()<o2.length())
  {

    return -1;
   }
    return o1.compareTo(o2);
   }
 });

 map.put("100_101","lll");
 map.put("100_102","lll");
 map.put("100_101_103","lll");
 map.put("100_101_104","lll");
 map.put("100","lll");

 System.out.println(map);
```

see [Java tutorial page for SortedMap.](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/java-sortedmap-and-treemap-tutorial-and-examples)

Comment: got the result {100=lll, 100_101=lll, 100_101_103=lll, 100_101_104=lll, 100_102=lll}

Comment: but my expected result is

Comment: {100=lll, 100_101=lll,100_102=lll, 100_101_103=lll, 100_101_104=lll}

Comment: i want to order by number of underscore occurences

Comment: kindly review the updated Version .it will result" {100=lll, 100_101=lll, 100_102=lll, 100_101_103=lll, 100_101_104=lll}"

Comment: yes i got it.but when i enter map.put("200","lll"); then it gets the error

Comment: @perera are you talking about my code or Neremeen's ? 'cos my code is working fine. Just tested.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 allows underscores ("_") in the numeric literals as per the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html).
TreeMap can be used here, the map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys

```
    TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
    map.put(100_101,"lll");
    map.put(100_102,"lll");
    map.put(100_101_103,"lll");
    map.put(100_101_104,"lll");
    map.put(100,"lll");

    for(Entry<Integer,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
          Integer key = entry.getKey();
          String value = entry.getValue();
          System.out.println(key + " => " + value);
    }
```

This can do the job!

Comment: True, but that's not really the problem here... The `TreeMap` should be explain ... (I missed that in your code at first)

Comment: No, it won't work like this in this case. Here he wants to compare the last integer only i.e. last integer after "_"

Comment: Since underscores are ignored, e.g. 100_101 becomes 100101 and 100_101_103 becomes 100101103, so 100_101 will come before 100_101_103  in the order.

Comment: @mrinal are you sure? Try it... 
`map.put(100_101,"lll");
        map.put(101_103,"lll");
        map.put(100_101_105,"lll");
        map.put(102_101_104,"lll");
        map.put(100,"lll");`

Comment: @mrinal I've already tested your code.. it gives output like this `100 => lll`
`100101 => lll`
`101103 => lll`
`100101105 => lll`
`102101104 => lll` . Please review what o/p he wants.. No offence bro..

Answer (score 0):

A Tree map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys. So you can use `TreeMap<String>`. find this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

If you are using `HashMap<String>` then you can do following

Get all the keys in sorted order as follows

```
Set<String> sortedKeys = new TreeSet<>(map.keySet());
```

or

```
List<String> sortedKeys=new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
Collections.sort(sortedKeys);
```

and then loop through this Set or List and get the values from Map and print.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this as I can see you want to sort based on last `Integer` of the `String` i.e. for `100_101` you want to sort based on `101`. You need to implement `comparator` to satisfy this. Here's the code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>(new CustomComparator());
        map.put("100_101", "lll");
        map.put("100_103", "lll");
        map.put("100_101_102", "lll");
        map.put("100_101_104", "lll");
        map.put("100", "lll");
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}

class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        int a, b;
//Used this because your key may or may not contain "_"
        if (str1.contains("_")) {
            a = Integer.parseInt(str1.substring(str1.lastIndexOf('_') + 1));
        } else {
            a = Integer.parseInt(str1);
        }
        if (str2.contains("_")) {
            b = Integer.parseInt(str2.substring(str2.lastIndexOf('_') + 1));
        } else {
            b = Integer.parseInt(str2);
        }
//        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str1.substring(str1.lastIndexOf('_')+1))+"---"+Integer.parseInt(str2.substring(str2.lastIndexOf('_')+1)));
        return String.valueOf(a).compareTo(String.valueOf(b));
    }

}
```

Comment: You'll get output like this: `{100=lll, 100_101=lll, 100_101_102=lll, 100_103=lll, 100_101_104=lll}`